# MIPS Code Cycle Time

Tags: c, assembly, mips

I need help with a task of determining the number of cycles for the MIPS code below.

My main issue is with determining if the condition is not met, is the if statement still executed (thus adding to the number of total cycles)

Assuming a single cycle implementation scheme i.e., each instruction requires
one clock cycle to execute.
1. What is the number of cycles required to execute the code when
a. s==0?
b. s==1?

This is what I have come up with myself:

a. 9 cycles

b. 8 cycles (it does not do the instruction contained in the if statement, and does not jump to the endif statement - (goes to the function) then the final endif.

This is the sample of MIPS:

```
main: 

 # Evaluate the expression.

 # Put the final result in a0 to prepare for the syscall.

addi    $sp, $sp, -4    # Make space on stack.
sw  $ra, 0($sp) # Save return address.

li  $t0, 1      # Put 0 in a register 
li  $a1, 4      # Put 4 in a register 
li  $a2, 6      # Put 6 in a register 

if: bne   $t0, $zero, else    # (i == 0) ?

add $v0, $a1, $a2   # v0 = a1 + a2

j  endif

else:   jal func

endif:
add $a0, $v0, $zero

li  $v0, 1
```

So I need to determine the number of cycles if a. s = 1, and b. s = 0 assuming that each instruction will take 1 cycle.

The C code for this is

```
main()
{
int A; a=4; b=6; s=3;
int function(a,b);
if (s==0)
A = a+b;
else
A = function(a,b)
return;
}
# Function to multiply two numbers
function(z,y)
{
int TMP;
TMP = z × y;
ret
```

Apologies for formatting. My first post on this forum and still working things out. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you should count the `bne` no matter whether the condition is true or not. You should also add up the cycles for the `func` unless specifically told not to.

Comment: Yes we are only supposed to count the number of instructions executed in the main body of the code down to endif:
add $a0, $v0, $zero

So, do I still count the 'add' inside the if statement even if the statement is not true?

Comment: This is a tough homework problem!

Comment: Since MIPS has branch delay slots, you also have to count the instruction following a branch, regardless whether it was followed or not. If the instruction following the branch is not executed on the followed branch, you need to add a NOP for the non-followed execution. Also, pipelining.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you want to approximate the time (by instruction counting) or determine the actual execution time, you have to count the `if` instruction no matter what.

In most modern CPUs, any flavor of jump instruction includes some penalties—maybe (for some CPUs) even when a conditional branch is *not* taken!

Penalties arise from [cache misses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Cache_miss), [pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28computing%29) perturbations, and [branch prediction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor).

Since I don't understand what this statement means, I am not dissecting the code path further.

```
TMP = z × y;
```